# Use of Resistor in PinWheel Exercise

Tags: resistor

I'm working on project 9 of the Arduino starter kit - the motorized pinwheel.

Here is the schematic:

[image]
(if img not showing: https://goo.gl/tqZmKD)

My question is, why is the 10k resistor needed after the switch? Why can't it just go straight to ground? The switch's output just connects to a digital pin, it doesn't care how much voltage there is, correct?

Thank you!

EDIT**: Additional help from the arduino forums:
The resistor is needed so when the switch is closed you don't short the supply
to ground.  Switch open the resistor pulls the signal to ground and no current
flows, when the switch is closed it forms a resistive divider with the 10k
(switch contacts might have 0.01 to 0.1 ohms resistance or so), thus pulling
the signal to Vcc, but with only 0.5mA flowing through the 10k resistor.

Replace the 10k with a wire and you'd simply overload the supply completely and
perhaps weld the switch contacts shut.
[Arduino Forums](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=328353.new#new)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a pull-down resistor.

A pull-up or pull-down resistor is used the make sure that the input of a digital device is confined to strict logic levels, i.e +Vdd (positive, or HIGH) or GND (Ground, or LOW).

With the switch open and no resistor present, the Arduino pin is neither high nor low. It will *probably* read as low if you tried `digitalRead()`, but there's no guarantee. The probability of the pin being one or the other changes according to the layout of the PCB and other external factors; the pin is termed 'floating' because it could be at any voltage between Vdd and GND.

However, if you apply a pull-(somewhere) resistor you force the Arduino pin to one of either Vdd (up) or GND (down) *until you press the switch*, at which point the Arduino pin switches state.

If you removed the resistor and joined the switch directly to ground, what happens when the switch contacts close?

Think about it...

One side of the switch connected to Vdd.

The other side is connected to the Arduino and GND.

Close the switch, *I dare you.*

**Vdd is now connected to GND**

Comment: Apologies - I didn't understand that. The switch controls whether or not voltage will continue to the green wire and thus, the digital input (in this case, pin 2). If switch is closed, voltage will continue to pin 2 and it will read HIGH. If switch is open, no voltage will pass through and the pin will read LOW. Is this not correct? And thank you for your time!

Comment: @ZAR: There is no situation of "no voltage" here; there is either Vdd or there is GND.

Comment: Hmm, so how is there voltage if the switch is open and thus not completing the circuit? I thought there would only be current when the switch is pressed, closing the circuit... Clearly I am missing some fundamental knowledge ;)

Comment: @ZAR 'no voltage' and zero-volts ARE NOT THE SAME. **No voltage** is *no connection to anything*, **Zero Volts** is *connection to ground*.

Comment: ...and a digital pin that is not connected to anything is called **floating**. Any floating digital input could be either high or low, and you can't guarantee which (unless you read it of course). Floating digital inputs are thus highly inadvised. The same doesn't apply for *unused pins* - they can be left unconnected.

Comment: Aha, I did not know this. So we want to have 'Zero Volts' in order for the pin to read LOW, correct? But why do we need the resistor? Can't we just connect this straight to GND and achieve the same thing?

Comment: **NO !!** Read my answer again, starting at "Think about it..." Then read it again, and again, until you understand the very last sentence. Although you are correct with "[...] we want to have 'Zero Volts' in order for the pin to read LOW [...]"

Comment: You've explained well that we need to have a connection to GND so that we can pull the input to either Vdd or GND (and not allow it to float). Got it. You've also explained that the switch will, when closed, connect the Vdd with GND. Got it. Here's what I have from you: a) We must connect to GND. b) the switch will connect the vdd to GND. You've asked my question "What if I removed the resistor" and then said think about it. Perhaps there will be too much voltage headed toward the arduino? We can connect to GND without the resistor.. The Vdd will still connect to GND, so what here is missing?